How to use default MacOs version of PHP instead of the MAMP's
On an old Mac I used to run MAMP. I uninstalled it a few year ago. I have recently set up a new Mac laptop, migrating across my settings and am trying to get phpStorm set up however I am coming up against issues to do with MAMP.
I have installed composer but am getting this error
which composer
composer: aliased to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/composer

There is no MAMP folder
likewise I have installed a new version of php and am getting this following
which php
php: aliased to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.1.0/bin/php -c "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php8.1.0.ini"

I can find no reference to MAMP in any config files that I am aware of, any suggestions where it might be?
Please note that I wish to use the version of php installing in the os and NOT the MAMP versions as this no longer exists.

Found it, it was my ~/.profile file that contained the configuration
